# How to access elements inner two shadow dom

Tags: css, stenciljs, stencil-component

I'm using the follow web-component tree:

```
<x-typography>
  :shadow-root
    <x-select>
      :shadow-root
        <div class="select-container>
        </div>
    </x-select>
</x-typography>
```

And I need to override the `background-color` on `select-container`. I don't have access to `<x-select>` code, only `<x-typography>`.

I know how to `:host` and `::slotted` works, I tried:

```
:host(x-typography):host(x-select) .select-container
:host(x-typography):host(x-select) .select-container
:host(x-typography :host(x-select)) .select-container
```

But none of them work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `::part` pseudo-element and `exportparts` attribute for this. It allows you to make custom styles for inner Shadow DOM element.

You can specify a "styleable" part on any element in your shadow tree:

```html
<x-select>
  :shadow-root
    <header class="select-header"></header>
    <div class="select-container" part="container"></div>
</x-select>
```

And then you can specify custom styles for that part like:

```css
x-select::part(container){
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Also it works with other pseudo selectors like `:hover`, `:active`...

```css
x-select::part(container):hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

But it doesn't work with **nested parts**. So, you **cannot** use it like:

```css
x-select::part(container)::part(aside) {
}
```

For that purpose you need to export the part via `exportpart` attribute.

```html
<x-bar>
  :shadow-root
  <x-foo exportparts="some-box: foo-some-box"></x-foo>
</x-bar>
```

However, if you need to support IE11 then it might be not the best option. From the other hand, it's supported by all modern browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=%3A%3Apart

So, your example would look like:

```js
// x-select


render () {
  return (
    <Host>
      <div class="select-container" part="container"></div>
    </Host>
  )
}
```

```js
// x-typography


render () {
  return (
    <Host>
      <x-select exportparts="container: container"></x-select>
    </Host>
  )
}
```

```html
<!-- usage -->

<x-typography></x-typography>

<style>
  x-typography::part(container) {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

Here you can find a great explanation how `part` works: https://github.com/fergald/docs/blob/master/explainers/css-shadow-parts-1.md

Comment: Hi @ivan! It works but, just for record, I preferred to create some variables called *tokens* which I used to access and manipulate some style aspects, it's a common practice in design systems and was a better solution in my scenario.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are absolutely right! My former colleague has written a great article about Design Tokens: https://medium.com/@didoo/how-to-manage-your-design-tokens-with-style-dictionary-98c795b938aa